# How to select Activity which will be startActivity depending on what exactly push notification will be clicked??? (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, push-notification

So, I have an application which uses push notifications of different purposes. When you click on these notifications it will always show the only Activity - SearchActivity, because it is in a code of onMessageRecieved fun in a class FirebaseMessagingService:

```
private const val CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel"

 class FirebaseService: FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        var sharedPref: SharedPreferences? = null

        var token: String?
            get() {
                return sharedPref?.getString("token", "")
            }
            set(value) {
                sharedPref?.edit()?.putString("token", value)?.apply()
            }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(newToken: String) {
        super.onNewToken(newToken)
        token = newToken
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)

        val intent = Intent(this, **SearchActivity::class.java**)
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val notificationID = Random.nextInt()

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel(notificationManager)
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
            .setContentText(message.data["message"])
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gaz)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager) {
        val channelName = "channelName"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
            description = "My channel description"
            enableLights(true)
            lightColor = Color.GREEN
        }
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

The question is - How to use different Actvities as first Activity while app opening depending on what notification was clicked?? In other words - when push notification with "text X" is clicked we go to Activity1, when push notification with "text Z" is clicked we go to Activity3, etc...

Comment: Is the information of :text x", "text z" coming inside `message.data["message"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this way:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message)
    val msg = message.data["message"]
    var intent = null
    when(msg){
    "text X": intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity1::class.java)
    "text Y": intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity2::class.java)
    "text Z": intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity3::class.java)

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val notificationID = Random.nextInt()

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createNotificationChannel(notificationManager)
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
        .setContentText(message.data["message"])
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gaz)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()

    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createNotificationChannel(notificationManager: NotificationManager) {
    val channelName = "channelName"
    val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, IMPORTANCE_HIGH).apply {
        description = "My channel description"
        enableLights(true)
        lightColor = Color.GREEN
    }
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could also upvote the answer as it would help others in the community with same problem. Thanks.